# Writing a RDS file outside R

Tags: python, r, perl, file-io, cran

I need to feed an R code with a vector from an external source and be fast, so I want to avoid reading generic files, such as csv.
I thought that writing outside R a RDS file could be a good idea.

Is there any library or wrapper in  C, C++, Python, Perl able to write in RDS format?

P.S. If you know a better way, other than RDS, suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used `??`

```
??rds  # brings up ...
?readRDS   # from the base package.
```

(You perhaps want to adapt [the code](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/serialize.c) from `.Internal(serialize, ...)`?)

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to the right direction: the C code that implements the serialization. One smaller question: if I want to write externally a vector, should I use the function OutRealVec defined in the source you pointed out?

Comment: I don't think you have defined the problem specifically enough that anyone could start writing code. Eddelbuettel suggests using ProtocolBuffers for cross-platform capacity:  http://www.mail-archive.com/rcpp-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg03957.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use rpy2 in Python. I use the following in python3:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
saveRDS = robjects.r['saveRDS']
saveRDS(pd_dataframe, 'data.rds')
```

Comment: It generates error: `NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>'`